# Можно ли передавать данные между фильтрами?

Tags: java, servlet

У меня фильтр который обеспечивает авторизацию пользователя, но проблема в том что он нарушает single responsibility principle, он и в базу ходит что бы проверить существует ли пользователь, и сессию проверяет на наличие такого пользователя. И я хочу разделить этот фильтр на два. Но проблема в том что эти 2 проверки мне надо произвести в одном ветвлении условных операторов соответственно надо передавать данные. Как это можно сделать?

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    final HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;


    final HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);


    if (nonNull(session) && sessionContainKey(session)) {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp")
                .forward(req, res);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    } else if (userExistInDB(req, getDBExecutor(req))) { //Инструкции этого ветвления я хочу перенести в другой фильтр вместе с userExistInDB за которым стоит коннект с базой.

        setSessionAttribute(req.getSession(), req.getParameter("name"));

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/index.jsp")
                .forward(req, res);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

    } else {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp")
                .forward(req, res);
    }

}
```

Comment: Ахаха, удачи в соблюдении SOLID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (session != null && session.getAttribute("name") != null) { 
    // Сессия уже открыта. Продолжить нормальную обработку
    filterChain.doFilter();
} else {
    if (req.getParameter("name") == null) {
        // Нет ни сессии ни запроса авторизации. Показать страницу login
        req.getRequestDispather("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp").forward(...);
    } else {
        if (!userExistsInDb(...)) {                             
            // Неудачная попытка авторизации. Показать страницу login
            req.getRequestDispather("/WEB-INF/views/login.jsp").forward(...);
        } else {                                                       
            // Удачная авторизация. Создать сессию и продолжить нормальную обработку
            req.getSession().setAttribute("name", ...);
            filterChain.doFilter();
        }
    }
}
```

А передавать данные между фильтрами можно. Например в одном фильтре положить объект в request, в другом, соответственно, извлечь

Первый

```
req.setAttribute("Юстас-Алексу", "Штирлец  шел по лесу и напоролся на сук. Суки разбежались с визгом. Визг бежал первым.");
```

Второй

```
String fromUstas = req.getAttribute("Юстас-Алексу");
```